# I can’t see the Greek characters using Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

Your help will be appreciated for the following problem:

I have a tool which converts IBM I (AS400) spool file to PDF. 
The file has been copied to Windows environment.

On generated PDF I can’t see the Greek characters using Adobe reader v10.1.4. If I use Notepad to display the file, I can see the Greek characters.

It seems that following PDF keywords are not recognized from the PDF reader.

```
/BaseFont /Courier
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
```

I have tried to use various fonts and encoding (cp1253, ISO8859-7) with no luck.
On PDF reader folder there is the following file:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Resource\TypeSupport\Unicode\Mappings\win\CP1253.TXT
```

I believe somehow to tell PDF reader to use this encoding.

What actions required on our Win/PDF environment setup? What actions required on PDF file generation? (`/BaseFont`, `/Enconding`, etc)

Comment: @AlekosFer I'm not clear on the link to TeX here: there is no mention of TeX or a related tool being used in your post. Could you clarify this, as otherwise this may be 'off topic'.

Comment: I saw on Forum that there were discussions for Greek characters on PDF documents.
I am not using Tex, but if someone tells me how your tools generated PDF using the correct Greek encoding, I will arrange to do the same from my tool.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Windows XP? if so, [this tutorial](http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5519/~/asian,-cyrillic-and-greek-characters-are-not-displayed-in-pdf-files-on-a) might be of help.

Using [this font](http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/fonts.asp) may also prove itself helpful to you.

In Windows 7, it is said that changing the keyboard to Greek when converting solves the issue preety well somehow (weird tho).
Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880970/searching-for-greek-characters-within-a-pdf-document , credits to @Chogg